# How to fix animation glitch in css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple side-menu with animation that matches to it's width changes. When the menu is closed i want to show only icons, and when it's open i want to display both - icons & text. 
The animation works fine, but there is some sort of a glitch when toggling...it's seems like when the text appears it's breaks line with the icon.
How can i delay the text appearence accordigly when the menu opens?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/qdyj5rnm/5/)

HTML

```
     <div ng-app class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
          <div class="side-menu-wrapper" ng-class="{'menu-open':!!isMenuExpanded, 'menu-closed':!isMenuExpanded}">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-item">
                <i class="fa fa-cog">
                  </i><span>
                    First item</span></li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                <span>
                    First item</span></li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                <span>
                    First item</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper {
      background-color: rgb(41, 44, 90);
      height: 100vh;
      transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper span {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed {
      width: 15%;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed span {
      /* display: none;
      opacity: 0; */
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper.menu-open span {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .side-menu-wrapper.menu-open {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .list-item {
      background-color: transparent;
      color: rgb(161, 165, 224);
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(161, 165, 224);
    }
```

Angularjs

```
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isMenuExpanded = false;
    $scope.toggleSideMenu = function() {
      $scope.isMenuExpanded = !$scope.isMenuExpanded;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by setting `height: 0;` in `.side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed span`

Change

```
    .side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed span {
      /* display: none;
      opacity: 0; */
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

To

```
   .side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed span {
      /* display: none;
      opacity: 0; */
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

And

```
   .side-menu-wrapper span {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

To

```
   .side-menu-wrapper span {
      margin-left: 5px;
      opacity: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on this [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yLd9v4j/2/)

Here is the new CSS that you have to use:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.side-menu-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(41, 44, 90);
  height: 100vh;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in;
}

.side-menu-wrapper span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed {
  width: 15%;
}

.side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed span {
  /* display: none;
  opacity: 0; */
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.side-menu-wrapper.menu-open span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  opacity: 1;
  
}

.side-menu-wrapper.menu-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;

  width: 100%;
}



.list-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(161, 165, 224);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(161, 165, 224);
}
```

---

### More details about your Glitch

First of all I updated the following class by removing the `height: 0;` in your transition, that was making a conflict:

```css
.side-menu-wrapper.menu-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
  /*height: 0;  This line make a conflict and is not needed */ 
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

### Possible improvements

On the class below you can also work on the fact that your menu once wrapped don't display only the icons but also a weird margin on the right

```
.side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed {
   width: 15%;
}
```

Try something like:

```
.side-menu-wrapper.menu-closed {
   width: 5.5%;
}
```

Comment: @RoyBarOn It is fixed and should works now if you wanna try it.